# Dynamic repeater with Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have the problem and not find the solution on Internet. I am using the repeater control the use add the check boxes. First time i have the array length 10 and i bind this array to repeater and also use the label property of check box to bind the label. First time it work fine but the second time i change the array length from 10 to 5. I passed this array to repeater data provider but it through the exception of Null. I didn't recreate the component but only change the array length on button click event.

Comment: #Adnan Siddique can you add some code here?

Comment: DataGroup is much more convinient component in Flex 4 to use for such purpose

Answer (score 0):

Adnan, have you tried this

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/29/displaying-checkbox-controls-using-the-repeater-in-flex/

Consider providing your code next time you post any question so that it can be checked.